# Mapbasic Record Count Legend

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

[image: Mapinfo Unchecked Record Count]

Is there any way to check/activate the 'Show Record Count' through Mapbasic instead of manually checking it in MapInfo like with the Range?

```
Open Window Legend
Set Legend Layer Prev Display on Shades on Title "Query On Unlisted Bus. Establishments" Subtitle " of Table " + TabName Ascending On 
    Ranges  "Listed Businesses"  Display On, "Unlisted Businesses" Display On  
CLOSE TABLE BUSMAST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set Legend Layer Prev 
  Display on Shades on 
  Title "Query On Unlisted Bus. Establishments" 
  Subtitle " of Table " + TabName Ascending On 
  Ranges "Listed Businesses"  Display On, "Unlisted Businesses" Display On
  Count Off
```

The `Count` keyword controls whether the Record Count is shown. Use `On`/`Off` to turn the Record Count on or off.

Comment: Thank you. It works.